# How to get the number of breakpoint which triggers the STOP in GDB

Tags: c++, gdb

I am using GUD in Emacs to debug C++ program. I setup some breakpoints, and the program stopped. How could I get the number of that breakpoint which triggered the STOP.

So I can apply commands on it. Such as disable the breakpoint temporally.

Thanks

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but does `info breakpoints` (or the short-end `i b`) make the job and display what you want ?

Comment: GDB already tells me which breakpoint it broke at. Doesn't yours? `Breakpoint 1, main () at STL_vector_int.cpp:15` / `15         cout << II.size() << endl;`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The **info breakpoints** command lists all the BPs. But not the one that triggered the break. I really expect the information as in #Lightness Races in Orbit#'s answer. But it never shows in my Emacs windows/buffers.